# Help with cross-platform script - #IF defined()

Tags: c++, if-statement, cross-platform, defined

I'm new to C++
I'm writing a crossplatform script, here is the part I need help with:

```
#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32) ||  defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__TOS_WIN__) ||    defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__CYGWIN32) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__BORLANDC__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
#define M_OS_WIN
#elif defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__) || defined(linux) || defined(__gnu_linux__) ||    defined(__GNUC__)
#define M_OS_LINUX
#else
#error "OS NOT SUPPORTED";
#endif
```

Which of these are the correct values(which are obsolete, should I add others)?

1. I need the windows part to be compatible with `<conio.h>`.
2. I need Linux part to be compatible with g++ (`<unistd.h>` and `<termios.h>` should work).
3. Is MACOS g++ compatible? (Is the line below correct?);

   `#elif defined(Macintosh) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)`
4. Is this the correct way to check if the compiler is MS Visual Studio - `#if defined _MSC_VER`?

Comment: There are number of cross-platform libraries that shield you from this sort of preprocessor madness, such as Boost and ACE.  Such libraries generally provide a common interface across many platforms, including the ones you're interested in.  I'd recommend using them if at all possible.  I realize that you're new to C++, and that there may be a bit of learning curve in using such libraries, but I believe they will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

A collection of all current (and outdated) macros defined for the pre-compiler on each platform/system/architecture is available at SourceForge.  Check out the [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html) project.

In my cross-platform projects, I usually come up with a custom name for each use case and define it to be something like:

```
#define OS_WINDOWS (defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__TOS_WIN__) ...)
```

Such that the rest of my code depends only a simple

```
#include "configure.h" // defines OS_WINDOWS, etc.
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
   // Windows-specific stuff here.
#endif
```

Comment: I saw that page, put I haven't heard most of these OS-es.

Comment: @mexus: you don't have to support them all.  Also, notice the page on "standards" for POSIX and such.  It should help a lot with handling the dozens of variants in the *NIX family.

Comment: @rubenvb: I put Windows as an example. It might not be as obvious for other systems.

Comment: é: I understand, but there are a lot of nice standardized macro's for Windows (`_WIN32`), Linux (`linux`), and MacOSX (`__APPLE__`). No need to go all out full monty on these things...

Comment: Methinks you meant to use `#if OS_WINDOWS`, not `#ifdef OS_WINDOWS`, given the way you `#define`'d the preprocessor identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, every compiler will provide predefined macros for determining the platform. You should search the `predefined macro` for the particular compiler.

For example: For MSVC the prefined macros are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)

***Is MACOS g++ compatible?***
Yes
The compiler which comes with Apple's XCode tools package is basically g++ but they have hacked on it a little.

***(Is the line below correct?***

```
#elif defined(Macintosh) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
```

You also need to add

```
#elif defined(macintosh) || defined(Macintosh) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
```

Check this specifically [**here**](http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html#sec17).

***Is this the correct way to check if the compiler is MS Visual Studio - `#if defined _MSC_VER`?***

Yes, as per exceprt from the predefined macros for MSVC link I gave above.

*It evaluates to the major and minor number components of the compiler's version number. The major number is the first component of the period-delimited version number and the minor number is the second component.
For example, if the version number of the `Visual C++ compiler` is `15.00.20706.01`, the `_MSC_VER` macro evaluates to `1500`.
In `Visual Studio 2010`, `_MSC_VER` is defined as `1600.`*

Comment: warning: the Intel compiler also defined `_MSC_VER`

Comment: Is Intel compiler compatible with <conio.h> ?

Comment: To answer my own question: YES, just tried it (the windows version), didn't try the Linux version...

Haven't compared the intel compiled exe with the one from vc2010, but It's double the size....